# OpenQuery Macro in Access - Update Parameters

Tags: ms-access

I have set up a query as shown in the attached picture.

The startDate and endDate parameters are linked to a text box in one of my forms.

If I run the query by itself without using the macro and enter the parameter values in manually, I get the expected result.

However, if I run the query using the macro I get an empty table. Its like the macro is not passing the textbox values into the parameters?

Is there anything glaringly wrong with my OpenQuery macro setup?

KR

Chris

[image: Textbox Setup]
[image: OpenQuery]

Comment: Why open a query object? Users should not interact with tables and queries. Bind query to form or report and open that. I don't use dynamic parameterized queries, I apply filter to form or report. Edit question to show the SQL statement of query. After entering value in textbox, must move away from that textbox for the input to be in effect.

Comment: I tested query and macro setup and it works. No, cannot see anything glaringly wrong except dates are international format. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html